# Clean way of using subclass and superclass pojo together in java

Tags: java, inheritance, design-patterns, extends

I have two classes say, `class A` and `class B extends A`. I need to call a method `func(List<A> list)`. In the parameter list i should be able to pass a list which can contain objects of class A and class B. Now i need to process them separately based on the instance type.

The class B is a newly introduced class and class A and func existed from before. I am wondering if there is a clean way to process new subtype of class A inside func, or is there any design pattern that i can use here.

Comment: You're probably looking for the "visitor design pattern"

Comment: Look up "visitor design pattern" and "double dispatch" which is what you appear to be trying to achieve.